# Exception while using getJdbcTemplate().queryForList in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dao

I am trying to use Spring `getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql,params)` to fetch list of records from the oracle db.
Searched SO as well as google but could not get a proper solution.
The problem is that if i run the same query in the SQL Developer it runs without any issue but if i try to call the same query by passing parameters from my Java code JDBC template its throwing exception.

Dao Code:

```
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    paramMap.put("CODE", Code);
    paramMap.put("NAME", Name);
    List statusCodesDetails  = super.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(selectSQL,paramMap);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT STATUS FROM PROCESS P,TRANSACTION R WHERE P.FILE_ID = R.FILE_ID and P.CODE = :CODE AND R.NAME = :NAME
```

In the query above both the `P.CODE` and `R.NAME` are Varchar.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [

           SELECT STATUS FROM PROCESS P,TRANSACTION R WHERE P.FILE_ID = R.FILE_ID and P.CODE = :CODE AND R.NAME = :NAME

        ]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Can anybody please let me know what is the issue here and what i am doing wrong.

**Update:**

I was able to get it working by using the ? instead for the named parameters since i was using simplejdbctemplate. I think there is some problem while using named parameters in jdbctemplate.

Modified SQL:

```
SELECT STATUS FROM PROCESS P,TRANSACTION R WHERE P.FILE_ID = R.FILE_ID and P.CODE = ? AND R.NAME = ?
```

Modified Code:

```
List statusCodesDetails  = super.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(selectSQL,new Object[]{CODE , NAME});
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Thanks
Vikeng21

Comment: Is your `getJdbcTemplate()` `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` ? Otherwise you should use query with `?` placeholders, and specify parameters by index.

Answer (score 0):

please check the datatype in DB and datatype in java compatibility for each attribute you are retreiving.
sometimes varChar(1) will not work so use varchar(2) like this..if possible you can post both datatypes DB and Java

Answer (score 0):

Spring JdbcTemplate will guess the sql type , it seems it not working correctly for your data types.

Instead of using `Map<String, Object>`  use `MapSqlParameterSource`  , specify parameter types  using `addValue(String paramName, Object value, int sqlType)`.